# How to use recursion on divide and conquer to find A[i] = i

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I'm trying to use recursive binary search method in order to find when A[i] = i given a distinct number of 'n' elements sorted in ascending order.

I understand how to use the recursive binary search method given the target I need to search for, but I can't seem to implement when I have to increment key value by one and search for when A[i] = i.

```
public static int match_dac( int[] A, int n )
{
    return dnq(A, 0, n-1, 0);
} 

public static int dnq(int[] A, int left, int right, int key) {
    if (left < right) {
        int centre= (left + right) / 2;
         if (A[centre] < centre) {
            return dnq(A, left, centre, key+1); 
        } else if (A[centre] > centre) {
            return dnq(A, centre + 1, right, key + 1);
        } else {
            return centre;
        }


    }

    return -1;
}
```

This is what I have so far.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**

```
public static int match_dac( int[] A, int n )
{
    return dnq(A, 0, n - 1);

} 

public static int dnq(int[] A, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int centre= (left + right) / 2;
        if (A[centre] > centre) {
            return dnq(A, left, centre); 
        } else if (A[centre] < centre) {
            return dnq(A, centre + 1, right);
        } else {
            return centre;
        }
    } else if (left == right) {
        if (left == A[right])
            return left;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It works now, thank you for your help. I added in the last else if statement because my method didn't capture if the last element equaled to the corresponding index (ie. A[8] = 8 when size of array is 9, and no other hits exist other than last element). Other than that, flipping the signs and using the centre as the key worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: We need to know more about the desired outcome.  As described, this is not a single-valued task, nor is it naturally susceptible to binary search.  For instance, what if the array looks like [0, 0.5, 3, 3, 3, 7] ?  This has two hits (0 and 3), and a binary search on the entire array won't find the lower one.  Another bad case is [1, 1, 2, 7, 7, 8, 9] -- as best I can see, your code will search the right half of the list, missing the match at position 1.  If I've flipped your logic, then replace the 7 in the middle with a 2, and the search goes in the opposite direction again.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify the input. The input is a sorted array of N distinct integers. And if it has more than one hit, it wants the one thats closer to the middle of the array. Also, I understand my method doesnt work. Can you give me a tip as to how to implement increasing the key value one at a time within the recursion call?

Comment: That simplifies the problems considerably.  First of all, given sorted distinct integers, all of the hits must be contiguous.  Second, your search is significantly more valid than I first feared.  I'll work on the mechanics ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  You have a couple of basic problems.

- You're confused by the key because you don't use it -- and you don't
  need it.  **centre** serves the entire purpose.
- You have your logic reversed for the array bisection.  Switch the < and >.

Also, **match_dac** has a superfluous parameter: if we have **A**, we can trivially derive **n**.  Get rid of that parameter, and simply call

```
dnq(a, 0, length(A)-1)
```

This will handle everything except the multi-hit case.  To take of that, you'll need one bit of final logic.  When you find a solution, check where you are from the centre of the original array -- length(A)/2.  Use a while loop to move position i from **centre** in that direction, so long as

```
A[i] == i and i != length(A)/2
```

You don't have to check the middle element: either you're already there, or you know it's not a hit.

Can you make those changes?  I don't have a Java work environment fully installed on this machine, or I could just hand you working code.